# Text Feature Extraction using scikit-learn

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, nltk, scikit-learn

I am using the Scikt-Learn package to extract features from the corpus. My code is following:

```
#! /usr/bin/python -tt

from __future__ import division
import re
import random
import numpy as np
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from nltk.cluster.util import cosine_distance
from operator import itemgetter

def preprocess(fnin, fnout):
  fin = open(fnin, 'rb')
  fout = open(fnout, 'wb')
  buf = []
  id = ""
  category = ""
  for line in fin:
    line = line.strip()

    if line.find("-- Document Separator --") > -1:
      if len(buf) > 0:
        # write out body,
        body = re.sub("\s+", " ", " ".join(buf))
        fout.write("%s\t%s\t%s\n" % (id, category, body))
      # process next header and init buf
      id, category, rest = map(lambda x: x.strip(), line.split(": "))
      buf = []
    else:
      # process body
      buf.append(line)
  fin.close()
  fout.close()

def train(fnin):
  docs = []
  cats = []
  fin = open(fnin, 'rb')
  for line in fin:
    id, category, body = line.strip().split("\t")
    docs.append(body)
    cats.append(category)
  fin.close()
  v=CountVectorizer(min_df=1,stop_words="english")
  pipeline = Pipeline([
    ("vect", v),
    ("tfidf", TfidfTransformer(use_idf=False))])
  tdMatrix = pipeline.fit_transform(docs, cats)
  return tdMatrix, cats


def main():
  preprocess("corpus.txt", "sccpp.txt")
  tdMatrix, cats = train("sccpp.txt")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

My corpuses are(brief form):
corpus.txt

```
0: sugar: -- Document Separator -- reut2-021.sgm
British Sugar Plc was forced to shut its
Ipswich sugar factory on Sunday afternoon due to an acute
shortage of beet supplies, a spokesman said, responding to a
Reuter inquiry
    Beet supplies have dried up at Ipswich due to a combination
of very wet weather, which has prevented most farmers in the
factory's catchment area from harvesting, and last week's
hurricane which blocked roads.
    The Ipswich factory will remain closed until roads are
cleared and supplies of beet build up again.
    This is the first time in many years that a factory has
been closed in mid-campaign, the spokesman added.
    Other factories are continuing to process beet normally,
but harvesting remains very difficult in most areas.
    Ipswich is one of 13 sugar factories operated by British
Sugar. It processes in excess of 500,000 tonnes of beet a year
out of an annual beet crop of around eight mln tonnes.
    Despite the closure of Ipswich and the severe harvesting
problems in other factory areas, British Sugar is maintaining
its estimate of sugar production this campaign at around
```

The error message is :

```
v=CountVectorizer(min_df=1,stop_words="english")
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'min_df'
```

I am using python2.7.4 in Linux Mint.
Can anyone advice me on how to resolve this problem?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: My gut feeling is that the issue is with your `sklearn` version. I don't get this error with `sklearn 0.13.1`.

Comment: @Akavall: Thank you very much for your reply. I installed the total package as: sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev python-numpy python-setuptools python-scipy libatlas-dev libatlas3-base. then i have tried this code. So what should I do now?

Comment: What is your `sklearn` version? You can do `import sklearn`, `sklearn.__version__` to find that.

Comment: If you need to update your `sklearn` you can learn here how to do that http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html#

Comment: @Akavall: I am using 0.11 and when i am issuing command sudo apt-get install python-sklearn, it says,python-sklearn is already new version installed. :(

Comment: If you are using `0.11` then I am sure this is the problem. Unfortunately, I don't know how to update your sklearn version, but I think this is a fairly easy question, and you might want to ask it as a another question.

Answer (score 4):

You need a newer scikit-learn version. Get rid of the one from Mint:

```
sudo apt-get uninstall python-sklearn
```

Install the necessary packages for building a new version:

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy-dev python-scipy-dev python-pip
```

Then fetch the latest release and build it using pip:

```
sudo pip install scikit-learn
```

Comment: If OP already has `pip` couldn't he just do `sudo pip install -U scikit-learn`?

Comment: @Akavall: I don't think pip will uninstall a package installed with `apt-get`, so they might end up with two installed versions and all the confusion that entails.